# Using DocuSignSign Now over REST API without having to Request Signature

Tags: docusignapi

Which API call can be used to start the sign-in process and do the actual signing? Is it possible to start the signing process without Request Signature? This is in reference to the Embedd feature with the Sign Now button: http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign .

Also, are there any videos or code snippets/ samples available that show such an implementation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can absolutely start the signing process without requesting a signature over e-mail.  Here is a walkthrough in 5 different languages: C#, Java, Node.js (JS), PHP and Objective-C

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning

In general you need to create a DocuSign transaction (envelope) before you can host a signing session, so don't let that throw you off.  The basic steps to do what you are looking to do are:

1. GET demo.docusign.net/restapi/login_information
   Login and receive API version, and accountId and baseUrl
2. POST demo.docusign.net/restapi/:version/:accountId/envelopes
   Post the documents you want to sign and receive envelope information, including envelopeId
3. Get DocuSign Recipient View
   Receive Recipient View Url

You can get the code here:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works for me! :)  -Ergin

Comment: In this demo email request gets send because of `envDef.Status = "sent";`. I want to sigin right in my app without sending emails. Is that possible?